# Recieving JSON from AJAX Call with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mongodb

I am getting a users details from a MongoDB database like this:

```
$user=$collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user']['userid'])));
if (!empty($user)){
    json_encode($user);
    print_r($user);
}
```

I can get an entire JSON array from the AJAX but not individual elements - I get undefined:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'json',
    url: '../scripts/getUser.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

The actual JSON is structured like this:

```
username: john
password: hello
email: me@mailserver.com
```

I'm stuck.

Comment: What does that `alert(msg)` look like?

Comment: Like Array([username] => john [password] => hello)

Comment: Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 530360f5978c680c1000002a
        )

    [username] => calumg
    [email] => me@blueyonder.co.uk
    [password] => cal
)

Comment: You do realize that's PHP serialization. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the return value

```
$encoded = json_encode($user);
print_r($encoded);
```

The method you are using does not **encode** in place. It returns a *left side* value.

Comment: When I do console.log(msg.username) in .js I get undefined

Comment: @user3066347 Can you log on the server side to check the response? Also look at you XHR response in your browser debugger. Make sure you are using **both** the lines in the answer.

Comment: how do I access the values in the json?

Comment: It appears you have **another** question. There is plenty of [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) available for you to read. The basics are, read the link, look for `data` in the docs and you just get an object variable in return. If you have any more problems with that, then post another question.

Answer (score 1):

you returning array object from getUser.php but you display it as a normal variable

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'json',
    url: '../scripts/getUser.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(msg){
    $.each(msg,function(key,value){
        alert(value.id);
});    
}
});
```

i guess this will work..

Comment: but in ajax he mentioned type as json

Comment: Look at my answer. It's the server code that is wrong.

Comment: @Neil Lunn ya i agree he did that mistake but inside ajax success function he tries to display the object(msg) ..is that correct ?

Comment: I want to get at the values - alert(msg.username) does not work

Comment: @Eshwer for reference. He got a response. **Yes** was the response in the format he wanted? **No**

Answer (score 0):

```
               success: function (response) 
                {
                if(response != 'error')
                {
                    //parse into JSON
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);

                var HTML = '';
                          //extract single value using each 
                $.each(jsonObj, function(key, val) {

                    HTML += '<tr><td>' + val.id + '</td><td>' + val.first_name + '</td><td>' + val.last_name + '</td><td>' + val.gender + '</td>'
                   +'<td>' + dt + '</td><td>' + val.phone + '</td><td>' + val.mobile + '</td><td>' + val.email + '</td>'
                   +'<td>' + val.address + ',' + val.city + ',' + val.state + '</td><td>' + val.country + '</td>'
                   +'<td>' + val.zip + '</td><td>' + val.hobbies + '</td><td>' + 'INR ' +val.salary + '</td><td>' + val.countryCode + '</td>'
                   +'<td>' + val.username + '</td><td>' + val.pwd + '</td></tr>';

                });
```